Have the inbox improvements of a couple of years ago been rolled back?
A few minutes ago I opened my inbox -- I do not remember for certain which page I was on, but it was probably a chat page -- and managed inadvertently to mark all of the unread entries as read, as if the changes mentioned in Inbox improvements: marking notifications as read/unread, and a filtered inbox view have been undone.  The red box holding the number of unread items (and the green box holding the sum of recent reputation changes) had an unfamiliar rectangular appearance rather than the current appearance with semicircular ends.
I had been keeping a number of unread items with the intention of returning to some of them later, so this is somewhat distressing.  I therefore have two questions:

Has the behavior of the inbox been changed again?

Is it possible to restore the items that I recently unintentionally marked as read to their previous unread state, or, if not, to obtain a list of these items?


In addition, if this is because the inbox changes were not implemented on the chat pages, has this already been reported?  Are there plans to fix it?


Has the behavior of the inbox been changed again?

The answer is that it has not which is the actual problem. The old inbox used to mark everything as read when opened. In some places on the network, that is still the behaviour, because it is not using the new inbox features:

I do not remember for certain which page I was on, but it was probably a chat page

In Inbox improvements are live this is explicitly stated:

Note: opening the inbox in chat will automatically mark all messages as being read until the changes will be applied there.

The changes are still not applied there.


Is it possible to restore the items that I recently unintentionally marked as read to their previous unread state, or, if not, to obtain a list of these items?

You can only mark items as unread individually by hand from the notification inbox on the top right of the page if you click the envelope button on each message:

Note: only the inbox on the top right works for this, the global inbox in the network profile does not allow marking things as unread.

Aha, I see.  So that tells me why this happened but doesn't respond to the support request.  Serves me right for asking two questions in one.

Well, you can mark individual messages as unread. But has to be done by hand. There is no automated "undo read" functionality. I'll update the answer with this information.

Only chat and Area 51 has the old inbox, while stackexchange.com has some odd hybrid. On se.com clicking the inbox won't reset the count, however it doesn't have all the new features in its inbox. (I think)
